# ASP.NET: How to get values from a selected row from GridView control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I have added a GridView control on my ASP.net webpage and data bound it to a `List<>` the list contains a collection of a simple custom objects which is defined as:

```
public class PersonRecord
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

I have set `AutoGenerateSelectButton` to true and and attached an event handler to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. I can see my event handler fires and I can get the selected row index by using `MyGridView.SelectedIndex`.

**My question is**: how do I use the selected row index to get the PersonId for the selected record?

I thought `MyGridView.Rows[MyGridView.SelectedIndex].Cells[0]` would do it but it doesn't because MyGridView.Rows.Count is 0.

TIA

Comment: IF MyGridView.Rows.Count is 0 it means that there is not data in your grid view. First Bind the gridview then you can get the data using 'MyGridView.Rows[MyGridView.SelectedIndex].Cells[0].Text'

Comment: He would not be able to use the select button if not initially bound. Not sure what is happening after that, as there is no code here.

Comment: Make sure you are not wiping your GridView in the page load before you hit your event handler (use if (!IsPostback))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you storing the data from your GridView on the server (session, viewstate, or are you not doing so?).  Since you have the selected row index, you just need to get your datasource again.  If you persist it in session, then you can just get that session object and get find the object at the index the user selected.

Comment: I wasn't persisting it but I think this would work. I assumed I was able to get the data back via the GridView.

Answer (score 2):

Just because I have not played with web applications in awhile, I decided to see if this was something I could dupe. Alas, to no avail. This works fine for me:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var persons = CreatePersons();
            GridView1.DataSource = persons;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private List<PersonRecord> CreatePersons()
    {
        var person = new PersonRecord
                         {
                             PersonId = 1,
                             Name = "greg",
                             Title = "Supreme Coder",
                             Description = "Nada",
                             Notes = "foo bar"
                         };

        var person2 = new PersonRecord
        {
            PersonId = 2,
            Name = "Sam",
            Title = "Junior Coder",
            Description = "Nada",
            Notes = "foo bar"
        };

        var list = new List<PersonRecord> {person, person2};

        return list;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var row = GridView1.Rows[0];
        var cell = row.Cells[1];
        var value = cell.Text;


    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
        var row = GridView1.Rows[index];
        var nameCell = row.Cells[2];
        var name = nameCell.Text;

        Label1.Text = name;
    }
}
```

Yours most likely fails as you are selecting the select column (cell[0]), but I would think you should get something out of this cell (have to play with it). It could also be a bad pattern for binding.